# Moodle 3.8.3 - 504 Gateway Timeout Error When Saving Courses

Tags: php, moodle, http-status-code-504

After migrating from SiteGround to AWS for our server, we've encountered a problem with saving Moodle courses. Despite adjusting the PHP timeout and making other necessary updates, we're consistently facing a 504 Gateway Timeout error when attempting to save courses in the Moodle administration interface. This issue is impacting our workflow, and I'm seeking assistance to troubleshoot and resolve it. Currently, we are using Moodle version 3.8.3. Any guidance or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

[image]